# User.IsInRole("User") Not working My online server but it is working on my local system when using online sql server database both mode

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: Welcome to SO. :) Please show some code. Which IP/hostname and port are you using? 127.0.0.1:1433?

Answer (score 1):

Is a connection or firewall problem check that. Probably you don't configure it correctly in production.
See this page [fix-error-code-26](https://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/fix-error-code-26/)

Comment: Thank You!
But same sql server properly working on my local system.